# Capitalize Input Fields with JavaScript But Account for Special Cases

Tags: javascript

I am using the toUpperCase() method to capitalize the first letter of a word in a form input field. Here's what my code looks like:

```
function validateFieldForceUppercase(type, name )
{
  if (name == 'firstname' )
  {
    //obtain the upper case value
    var firstName = nlapiGetFieldValue('firstname')
    var upperCase = firstName.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+firstName.substr(1).toLowerCase();

    //make sure it hasn't been set
    if (upperCase != nlapiGetFieldValue('firstname' ))
    {
      nlapiSetFieldValue('firstname', upperCase, false );
    }
return true;
}
```

Is it possible in JavaScript to auto-capitalize the first letter of each word in a form input field and also account for special cases such as "ABC Company" or a name like "McCarthy" can these be ignored by the code or corrected with some other solution?

NOTE: Some of the code given are NetSuite functions, in case there is any confusion.

Comment: You'd have to define the "special cases"

Comment: What you want requires a special dictionary which will look up for names like McCarthy or companies like ABC Company. There isn't something like this till now, you must define your own dictionary (dates).

Comment: Well that's a pain. Guess I'll just make due with what I have.